# GradientDrawable stroke outside only

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom button using this code:

```
Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartTest);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.buttonStartTest);
    v.setBackground( new DrawableGradient(new int[] { btnColor,btnColor, 0xffffffff }, 110,10));
    goButton.setText(getString(R.string.START_FORM));
```

And where the DrawableGradent looks like:

```
public class DrawableGradient extends GradientDrawable {
    DrawableGradient(int[] colors, int cornerRadius,int strokeSize) {
        super(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, colors);

        try {
            this.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
            this.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
            this.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
            int strokeColor = Color.argb(50, 0, 0, 0);
            this.setStroke(strokeSize,strokeColor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This results in a button that looks like this:
[image: resulting button]

This is what I want to get except that I want the stroke to only be on the outside of the button. How can I achieve this?

This is what the desired look is:
[image: desired look]

Thanks for your help! :)
/Daniel

Comment: Post one more image with a desired look

Comment: @pskink I've now updated with a desired look of the button.. thank you for helping

Comment: hmm, i dont think it can be done wirhout custom drawing - Drawable.draw(Canvas)